# Issues migrating Wordpress site from local to live with NextGen Gallery

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

I've migrated a local test of a Wordpress site to a live server but I'm encountering a weird issue. Everything works fine, but one of the plugins that I'm using (NextGEN Gallery) is attempting to download a few CSS and JS files from the old location at `127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/`.

I cannot figure this issue out for the life of me. I have done repeated searches for `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`, and `powwptest.1` or `powwptest` in the database through phpMyAdmin, I have manually searched the .SQL file with Sublime Text, and searched all 1600+ PHP files with Sublime Text to no avail. Absolutely nothing is found.

If there is no record of `127.0.0.1/powwptest.1` in the database or in any of the files, why is it still attempting to download from the local server?

A few of the calls, for an example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?ver=3.6
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js?ver=3.6
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=3.6
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/nextgen_fancybox_init.js?ver=3.6
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=3.6
http://127.0.0.1/powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/nextgen_fancybox_init.js?ver=3.6
```

I've cleared cache, cookies, tried in multiple browsers, and even used a third-party (Pingdom) to make sure I'm not crazy. They are all detecting the connection errors as well. I've tried updating the Wordpress plugin on the live server, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Give us an actual url so we can check it

Comment: Yep. you've got that written at the place this plugin gets included or referenced from there. Can you find a code where you include `powwptest.1/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js?ver=3.6`. You put it someplace right.. Show it how you did it.

Comment: The closest I've gotten in my 5 hours of searching is this code in the plugin's source: `// Install Fancybox 1.3.4
  $this->install_lightbox(
   'fancybox',
            'Fancybox',
   'class="ngg-fancybox" rel="%GALLERY_NAME%"',
   array('photocrati-lightbox#fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css'),
   array(
    'photocrati-lightbox#fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js',
    'photocrati-lightbox#fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js',
    'photocrati-lightbox#fancybox/nextgen_fancybox_init.js'
   )
  );` I've tried to work my way back and find the call to `powwptest.1`, but there is nothing!

Comment: There is `127.0.0.1` written someplace for sure

Comment: Here is that specific .php file on the SVN: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nextgen-gallery/trunk/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/class.lightbox_installer.php

Comment: No idea, try `grep` searching for 127.0.0.1 trough all files maybe..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36599/discussion-between-dachi-and-trey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally, hopefully this works for others having an issue with NextGen Gallery. From your WordPress dashboard, go to Gallery -> Other Options -> Lightbox Effects -> (Show Advanced Settings). At this point you can delete the `http://127.0.0.1/` etc. entirely from each entry. You'll have to do this once for each type of Lightbox.

It seems to me that this information is stored on a 3rd party server, otherwise there is no reason it could reappear in the DB.

Comment: yes that fixed my lightbox js and css paths.
But my close-button, next and prev button paths are not changed.
Does anybody has an idea feom where they can be changed?

Answer (score 3):

The new team that's been developing NextGen Gallery seems to have broken a lot of things. I've ran into some crazy problems with this plugin and site moves.

Try resetting permalinks as well as the plugin settings (which, if I recall correctly, you can do from the plugin settings page in WordPress). This won't clear your galleries, only settings set in the plugin settings.

Comment: Yes, it looks like many others are reporting this plugin as broken on Wordpress. Ah well, I'll have to start over or try something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent 3 hours of solving same issue. Finally, I've found out, look into DB

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_value like '%127.0.0.1%';
```

Comment: ok, there is a crazy bug in nextgen gallery. I've fixed data in database, reinstalled/upgraded plugin, and it created localhost/127.0.0.1 entries again

Comment: I figured it out for myself finally, hopefully this works for you. From your WordPress dashboard, go to Gallery -> Other Options -> Lightbox Effects -> (Show Advanced Settings).

At this point you can delete the http://127.0.0.1/ entirely from each entry. It seems to me that this information is stored on a 3rd party server, otherwise there is no reason it could reappear in the DB.